# SwipeView event handling

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

Following are the details of my development setup:Linux desktop: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Qt Version : 5.9.4 Open source

I am working on a small application which will demonstrate the hardware's screen responsiveness. E.g. If I have a SwipeView, with the application, I need to measure the time between the user action (i.e. end of swipe action on the screen) and the page (next or previous) change to appear. I am testing the application on x86 and later I will cross compile for the device.

Here my requirement is on end of user action, I need to get a signal to capture the time. Once the page is changed on swipe view I will again capture the time and then the difference of these 2 times will be my result.

For page change I can rely on the onCurrentIndexChanged() slot of SwipeView. But I am not finding any slot, which informs about the end of user's swipe action.

I tried using MouseArea. **onPress**, I am making **mouse.accepted = false**, and this allows the swipe to happen. But then I am not getting the **onRelease** event in the MouseArea, which is obvious from the MouseArea document.

So is there any way to handle this scenario?

Regards,
Bikash

Comment: I guess that the best way to solve the issue is the source code: [QQuickSwipeViewDelegate](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/dev/src/quicktemplates2/qquickswipedelegate.cpp) (I guess you have to focus on QQuickSwipeTransitionManager) and [QQuickSwipeView](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/dev/src/quicktemplates2/qquickswipeview.cpp)

Comment: If you want to test the responsiveness of the hardware, you will probably want to eliminate any extra time spent in irrelevant code in Qt, wouldn't you? In which case I would use e.g. [input handlers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickhandlers-index.html#input-handlers), such as DragHandler or TapHandler.

Comment: @Mitch thanks for the reply. seems like Input handlers were introduced from Qt 5.10. As mentioned i m using qt 5.9.4.

Comment: @folibis.. thanks for the reply. Do you mean, i need to make required changes in Qt source code and use the same? One more thing, SwipeView doesn't have a **delegate** property. Is there any relation between SwipeView and SwipeDelegate?